# How to test a function using jasmine-node which internally calls a function which returns a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, promise

I am just trying out jasmine-node. I need some help with promise resolution. I have simple js file

```
//dataService.js

var Q = require('q');
console.info("Q is "+Q);
exports.test = function() {
    console.warn("Will call promise now");
    this.getQuestions().then(function() {
        console.log("Test..");
    });
};

exports.getQuestions = function() {

    var deferred = Q.defer();
    for(i=0; i<=10; i++) {
        if(i===10) {
            deferred.resolve(i);
        }
    }
    return deferred.promise;
    // return {
    //  'Question1': 'What is your name'
    // }
}

//end of dataService.js



And the test is

// testspec.js


var assert = require("assert");
var q = require('q');
var testFile = require('../routes/dataService');
var fs = require('fs');


  describe('#indexOf()', function(done){
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function(done){
        console.log("Teststststst" + fs);
      assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(5));
      assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(0));
      spyOn(testFile, 'getQuestions').andCallFake(function() {
            console.warn("Spy Called********************");
            var deferred = q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(1);
            console.info("passing 1****");  
            //done(1);
            return deferred.promise;
      });
      spyOn(console, 'log');
      testFile.test();
      console.info("Testststststsinggggggggg");
      expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Test..");
      console.info("Done*****************");
    })
  });
```

//end of test file

Now as you can see I am calling testFile.test() function which is nothing but the test function in dataService.js. This function calls the getQuestions() in the dataService.js (same file), which returns a promise. I have mocked the getQuestions() function in my test, it is getting called and is resolving the promise, but my test() success method is not getting called, so my test is failing.

Answer (score 2):

Your `getQuestions` method never resolves the promise.

You have a loop running from `0` to `9` but you only resolve it if `i === 10`.

Change:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if(i===10) {
        deferred.resolve(i);
    }
}
```

To:

```
deferred.resolve(10);
```

As a general tip methods that call functions that return promises *should return promises themselves* so you can easly test them and hook on their completion. For this reason I'd make `.test` return a promise (rather than just call it)

Comment: Hey that i<10 is i<=10, it is a typo.....sorry.......the test is not working....actually I have spied on the getQuestions.....and the spied method is getting called....but the test methods success method is not called

Answer (score 0):

```
I was able to run the test by returning a promise from the test() function.


//dataService.js

var Q = require('q');
console.info("Q is "+Q);
exports.test = function() {
    console.warn("Will call promise now");
    return this.getQuestions().then(function() {
        console.log("Test..");
        return 'success';
    });

};

exports.getQuestions = function() {

    var deferred = Q.defer();
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if(i===3) {
            deferred.resolve(i);
        }
    }
    return deferred.promise;
    // return {
    //  'Question1': 'What is your name'
    // }
}

//end of dataService.js



//dataServicespec.js

var assert = require("assert");
var q = require('q');
var testFile = require('../routes/dataService');//include the dataService.js
var fs = require('fs');


describe('Tests', function(done) {
  it('should run the test properly', function(done) {
    console.log("Teststststst" + fs);
    var flag = false;
    var deferred;

    spyOn(testFile, 'getQuestions').andCallFake(function() {
      console.warn("Spy Called********************");
      deferred = q.defer();
      console.info("passing 1****");
      deferred.resolve(1);
      return deferred.promise;
    });

    spyOn(console, 'log');

    runs(function() {
      var p = testFile.test();
      p.then(function() {
        flag = true;
      });
    });

    waitsFor(function() {
      if (flag === true)
        return true;
    });

    runs(function() {
      console.info("Testststststsinggggggggg");
      expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Test..");
      console.info("Done*****************");
      done();
    });



  })
});

//end of dataServicespec.js


Thanx @Benjamin on you suggestion for returning a promise from test.
```